# A conflicting jar is being added to Maven dependencies - how to track down?

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have a dependency that I have added to my project:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I compile and run I get an error indicating a mismatch of signatures. Looking at my Maven Dependencies in my Java Build Path (Eclipse) I see a jar being added by Maven for Vaadin version 6.8.8. I have scoured my `pom.xml` and do not see that I have added that. I assume that this dependency is being added by another dependency.

I definitely want to use Vaadin version 7.0.5. As long as version 6.8.8 keeps getting included it will be an issue. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Once you have its output you can add a suitable exclusion.

Comment: Perfect! Actually using Eclipse there is a tab that creates the hierarchy of dependencies. Click on the problem child on the RH "resolved dependencies" side and it shows where the dependency is being generated from. Right button on the dependency on the LH side and mark it fro exclusion.

Comment: @EricSnyder The problem is that once you start second-guessing dependencies you run the risk of introducing incompatibilities.